# Blazor Server - deployed to IIS not loading sometimes

Tags: windows, server, blazor-server-side, iis-8

Good Day everyone

We created a Blazor Server application and deployed in on our web server (windows 2019) with IIS as our host, now the site is okay when deployed but, sometimes if there are too many users accessing the site of if few members are requesting too much,the site does not working properly,or it does not,the fix we are doing for this is to stop and start the app on the IIS, and this is not a best practice as we have to this again everytime the app is not working,we check the event log, but we did not see any errors, this scenario always happen on both of our staging and production, what do you think is the cause of this problem?? And how to fix it?

Edit: I have to clarify, according to our team they are only 10 people who is using the app, both prod and staging is encountering the issue, and I'm on dead end

Comment: You cannot expect a single server to host too many users, as Blazor Server consumes server side resources for each user it serves. Either you build a baseline based on performance analysis and then set up load balancing across a bunch of servers, or you switch to Blazor on WebAssembly that distributes resource consumption to the browser side.

Comment: Hi @LexLi  I updates the question, how to setup a load balancer for blazor server side?

Comment: @LexLi if we redeveloped this to webassembly this will take a while :(

Comment: Any load balancing solution with sticky session support should work for Blazor Server web apps, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18705 BTW, Blazor on WebAssembly doesn't really take too much effect (old examples are there like https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-i-convert-a-blazor-server-side-project-to-a-blazor-webassembly-project).

Comment: Are you properly disposing off resources? We also have a Blazor server application with 140-150 active users, hosted on IIS and we do not have any issue. See what happens when you add in logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-6.0 and what does it say on the event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

we put an Idisposable on our application, to dispose of resourcers, and we are currently checking if the application will still experience unresponsiveness after a number of people accessing the application, we also fix the javascript errors, that might be the cause of unresponsiveness

thank you for your comments and suggestions